# How to calculate the distance between two objects?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to calculate the distance between two objects, a rectangle and a circle. Where the circle is stopped and the rectangle is moving along a circle (using a path transition).

This if to calculate the distance from a moving vehicle to an obstacle in a lane.

```
 private double calculateDistanceBetweenAccidentAndVehicle()
 {
 //      Point2D v = new Point2D(vehicle.getX(), vehicle.getY());
 //      Point2D be = new Point2D(blockingObject.getCenterX(), 
 blockingObject.getCenterY());
 //      v.distan

  double vX = getGlobalX(vehicle);
  double vY = getGlobalY(vehicle);
  double bX = getGlobalX(blockingObject);
  double bY = getGlobalY(blockingObject);

  Point2D v = new Point2D(vX, vY);
  Point2D b = new Point2D(bX, bY);

  return v.distance(b);

}

  private double getGlobalX(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
      return 0.0;
   }
  double parentGlobalX = getGlobalX(node.getParent());
  return node.getLayoutX() - parentGlobalX;
  }

  private double getGlobalY(Node node) {
  if (node == null) {
      return 0.0;
  }
  double parentGlobalY = getGlobalY(node.getParent());
  return parentGlobalY - node.getLayoutY();
}
```

The results I am getting are not making sense. I get 1000 and it should reach 0 when the two object collide, the lowest value I got was 375.

Comment: An object consists of more than just a single point. Furthermore depending on the properties used your `getGlobalX/Y` methods won't result in the correct output. I'm not sure why you try to reinvent the wheel anyways? `Node` provides the [`localToScene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene(double,double)) method for this purpose that has the additional benefit of not ignoring transformations (scale, rotate, translate, ...).

Comment: I am new to javafx, it takes me more time than I want to understand certain things. I ended up using getBoundsInParent and it worked. Thanks.